# what does retrievable and replicable access meant for an object in salesforce schema?

Tags: schema

From the access level for an object in salesforce schema i understood queryable, deletable and creatable, but what does retrievable and replicable access meant for an object in salesforce schema? please suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **retrievable**---In general, you use Retrieve() when you know in advance the IDs of the records to retrieve. Use Query() instead to obtain records when you do not know the IDs or when you want to specify other selection criteria.
>
> **replicable**---If object does not have this access you cant use calls like getupdated(),getdeleted() methods .Example will be Accountshare,OpportunityShare etc

Comment: Additionally, it controls whether features such as getUpdated and getDeleted are supported.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/object-specific_requirements_for_data_replication.htm